# Moq - How to implement mock for method of generic base class?

Tags: c#, interface, mocking, moq

I have the following interfaces and service implemented like this:

```
public interface IParentInterface<T> where T : class
{
    T GetParent(T something);
}

public interface IChildInterface : IParentInterface<string>
{
    string GetChild();
}

public class MyService
{
    private readonly IChildInterface _childInterface;

    public MyService(IChildInterface childInterface)
    {
        _childInterface = childInterface;
    }

    public string DoWork()
    {
        return _childInterface.GetParent("it works");
    }
}
```

Here is my test for the **DoWork** method of **MyService** class:

- Create a new mock object of the child interface
- Setup the GetParent method of the parent interface
- Pass the mock object to the service constructor
- Execute the DoWork
- Expect to have the **resp = "It really works with something!" but it's null**

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    var mockInterface = new Mock<IChildInterface>();
    mockInterface
        .As<IParentInterface<string>>()
        .Setup(r => r.GetParent("something"))
        .Returns("It really works with something!");

    var service = new MyService(mockInterface.Object);

    string resp = service.DoWork(); // expects resp = "It really works with something!" but it's null

    Assert.NotNull(resp);
}
```

Other info:

- Moq 4.16.1
- .NET CORE (.NET 5)
- XUnit 2.4.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mock setup is saying to mock the method with `"something"` is passed in. You should change that to match what the class is passing in, e.g. `"it works"` or much easier is to allow any string using `It.IsAny<string>()`. For example:

```
mockInterface
    .As<IParentInterface<string>>()
    .Setup(r => r.GetParent(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns("It really works with something!");
```